# Stacking of Electrical extension boards

Tags: mains

Is it recommended to stack extension boards?

Output of 1st extension board - Input of 2nd extension board - Output of 2nd extension board - Input of 3rd extension board and so on ...

https://www.google.com/search?q=3+pin+extension+board&prmd=sivn&sxsrf=ALeKk03HYYNQX7eInEIX9WLxgfbuchHOfA:1595735413808&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW-vrTgerqAhWEbSsKHd4vBVsQ_AUoAnoECA4QAg&biw=360&bih=592

Comment: Only if all your devices use proportional less current.

Comment: Prashant Akerkar - Welcome :-) (a) When you say "extension board", I think you mean what elsewhere in the world may be called a "trailing mains extension" or similar. The Google image search link you gave is not totally clear, as it also includes images of Raspberry Pi extension boards, which are completely different! Do you mean something like [this](https://5.imimg.com/data5/YD/LR/MY-38922477/power-strip-500x500.jpg)? If so, it is better to give one clear image like that. (b) Please stop adding your signature to your posts; this breaks a site rule. I've removed it for you this time. Thanks

Comment: P.S. A more typical description of joining mains extension sockets in that way (IMHO), is "daisy-chaining" and that is a common search term in some parts of the world. I have never heard of "stacking" for such connections in this context before!

Comment: @SamGibson I mentioned Daisy chaining in my answer.

Comment: @SolarMike - Hi, Sorry for not mentioning your answer. I was focused on helping the OP to improve their question (e.g. suggesting a single, unambiguous link, not a page of Google images) and I only saw (and upvoted BTW :-) ) your answer, after I had posted my comments. I don't think it does any harm for the OP to have both of us telling them that a more common description (and therefore a better search term when doing research) is "daisy-chaining". No disrespect intended to you and, as you said, you mentioned the term as well - I just hadn't read your answer when I posted!

Comment: @SamGibson all good points, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Do remember that the total current cannot exceed the rating of the first extension board.

Given how **some** of those are made then the real limit should be 50% of what is stated.

Also many extension boards state that they should not be daisy chained or connected in the fashion you describe.